# How do parameter constraints work?

Tags: c#, constraints

What is going on behind the scenes when you do something like:

```
private static void AssertIsNotNull<T>(T x) where T : class{}
```

Is it possible to get the same effect by using something from the Win32 namespace?

The reason why I ask is I'm interested to know if you can constrain a parameter in C# 1.0.

Comment: Generics (and therefore generic constraints) are a compile-time feature. You can't constrain a generic parameter in C# 1.0, because C# 1.0 doesn't have generics at all. And they're nothing to do with Win32. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: They are not **parameter** constraints - they are **generic** constraints.

Comment: If you want a name for these things, you can use "typenames" -- that's what they're called in C++.

Comment: Generics in c# are not only a compile-time feature but also run-time as opposed to say C++ templates which are purely compile time.

Comment: I'm just interested in how C# actually checks whether it's a reference type or not.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave at compile time it is known.

Comment: It's not necessarily known at runtime for example if you call AssertIsNotNull by reflection. In that case I expect the runtime will thrown a TypeLoadException exception.

Comment: Friendly advice - sometimes the best way to learn is to grab ILSpy or Reflector, and just look at the code yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a type is a reference type or value type, without generics (which are only available since c# 2) you can use

```
if (typeof(MyType).IsValueType)
```

or if you have an Object obj:

```
if (obj.GetType().IsValueType)
```